# How to change the Item list of navigation drawer in tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I am using the navigation drawer with sliding tab in my app and I want to change the item list of the navigation drawer according to the tab. Like, In tab 1 navigation drawer with item 1 item 2 and in tab 2 navigation drawer with item 3 and item 4. 
Here is the code of my navigation drawer fragment class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);;
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerAdapter  = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    //recyclerAdapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    /*recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(),
            recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SubActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SubActivity.class));

        }
    } ));*/
    return view;
}


public List<Information> getData(){
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icons = {R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha,
            R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha};
    String[] title = {"Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"};

    for (int i=0; i<icons.length; i++) {
        Information information = new Information();
        information.setResIdImage(icons[i]);
        information.setText(title[i]);
        data.add(information);
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is code of tab class

```
public class Tab2 extends NavigationDrawerFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("The position is 2");
    return view;
}
}
```

So, I want to change the getData() method items of navigationDrawerFragment class from tab2 class.
Thank You.

Comment: Your question provides a lot of code that does not really seem relevant. It would be good if it were more specific - like, the specific bits of code that would make that operation happen and any problems you've had with implementing the code.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited my code and for now all tab fragment class displays same item list in navigation drawer from getData() method in navigationDrawerFragment class and I want to change that getData() method items in tab 2 and tab 3 with different item. I am new to android so I did not have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this

```
private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
private static String[] titles = null;
private static String[] icons = null;
...
public void setItems(String[] titles,String[] icons) {
    // drawer labels
    this.titles = titles;
    this.icons = icons;
    this.adapter.data = getData();
}

public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();

    // preparing navigation drawer items
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        navItem.setIcon(icons[i]);
        data.add(navItem);
    }

    return data;
}
```

to FragmentDrawer class